# Download zip/archive file of a Git repo including .git folder

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a `400MB` repository on Bitbucket and I want to download it in `zip`, actually `bz2` format to lessen the file size even more, and using a download manager. But downloading the repo this way will exclude the `.git` folder resulting to `fatal: Not a git repository...` (I have tried this on a repo with small file size to experiment).

Is there anyway to download the repo in an archive file that will include the `.git` folder? Or adding `.git` folder thru the command line? Or anyway I can download the `.git` folder only, for the specific repository?

Comment: `git clone --bare <repo_url>` might do what you want. Or just use `git clone <repo_url>` to get everything. `man git-clone`.

Comment: `git clone --bare` will download the whole size of the repository still. I was looking for a way to download the repo with the `.git` folder already intact, directly from their website and in `bz2` format using a download manager for faster download. Cloning thru the command line is too slow.

Comment: git compresses the files automatically before sending them. You might look at changing the compression settings (if you can)

Answer (score 1):

Clone the repo first to you local machine,  then zip it :)

I don't think Bitbucket has support for what you're looking for

Comment: `git clone` is too slow. I was thinking if I can download the repo in `bz2` format using download manager, with the `.git` folder already part of the download.

Comment: Apparently it is possible now. Check out repository's "Downloads" section